# what is replace option in import products in magento2

Tags: magento2

In magento2 import screen there is a field called import behaviour.it contain 3 options(add/update,delete,replace).

any one have idea how replace option will work?

Comment: just now i selected that option.it contains product ids will be regenerated

Comment: Track the usage of `\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE`. You'll get to `\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::_replaceProducts()`.